# How numeric promotion in a conditional assignment works in Java

Tags: java, double, types

Found some strange things in java.

Code:

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3.5);
    System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3);
    System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 + "" : 3.5);
```

Result:

```
1.8.0_40
2.0
2
2
```

What is it? Why integer value returns only if value for false is not a double or if string value added to value for true? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

This [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) documents the numeric promotion in Java. In section 2, it says that if either operand is of type `double` then the result is of type double. In this [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (which was added by @Januson), it is mentioned that:

> the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second **AND** third operands

Now, if we apply those two documents to our examples, we get the following:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

This is the version (release) of Java. It is a `String`.

```
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3.5);
```

In this case the compiler looks at the both parts of the conditional and decides the data type. (int)2.5 is an `integer` and 3.5 is a `double`. The result will be a `double`. So the integer part of 2.5 (i.e., 2) will be cast to a `double`.

```
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 : 3);
```

In this case, the compiler looks at 2 integers so the result is an `integer`. The first case gives an `integer` and the second case is also an `integer` so the result will be in `integer`.

```
System.out.println((true) ? (int)2.5 + "" : 3.5);
```

In this case, the compiler looks at the first case and takes the integer part which is 2. Now, because this number is appended to a string, it becomes a `String`. The result will also be a string. If you try to return 3.5, this will be returned as a `String` and not a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way ternary operator resolves its return type. Check its [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) for more information.

First expression returns double because 2.5 is first converted to int 2 but since third argument is double and int is convertible to double then return type for whole expression is double 2.0

Second return symply int 2 because 2.5 to int is 2 and return type is int.

Third first converts 2.5 to 2, then to String "2" and return type is String.